# Angularjs geo-location with existing data

Tags: geolocation

I am using angularjs in my application, its great working with angularjs. I have one problem inside angularjs geo-location with existing data. Consider code:

```
$scope.lat = 18.50;
$scope.long = 73.70;

$scope.places = [{placename: 'CCD',lat: 18.56,long: 73.50},{placename: 'HDFC bank',lat: 18.58,long: 73.40},{placename: 'Play ground',lat: 18.50,long: 73.72},{placename: 'Kids School',lat: 18.45,long: 73.78}];
```

I have latitude and longitude of one place and want to get places nearby 20km(providing radius) within `$scope.places`. So how can i get that.Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: what is "angularjs geo-location"? If this is a particular library (such as maybe [this one](https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation)) then you should reach out to the developer of the library.

Comment: angularjs geo-location its just reference for my problem.there they take location from google service and here i have data with me just to apply some business rule.

Comment: Then it's an algorithm problem and not related to AngularJs - so, it's off-topic

Comment: i am not saying its angularjs problem, but if you checked angularjs geo-location service they provide radius in there service.So i am just asking can i used this inside my problem.